# object selectors jquery validationEngine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm working with validationEngine's `onBeforeAjaxFormValidation(form, options)`.

I would like take the form and do it like this without the `id`:

```
$("#contactfor :input").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If `#contactfor` is the `id` of the same form you are using jQuery Validation Engine against. Then, you should be able to do something like this:

```
form.find(":input").prop("disabled", true);
```

Comment: I dont know why, but this way its works

$("form :input").attr("disabled", true);

Comment: @Dinamo, we don't know either if you don't provide more information. Anyways, that's applied to all forms in the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#form1').find("INPUT").attr('disabled',true);
```

Comment: i donr know why but this way it works fine

$("form :input").attr("disabled", true);